# Mimic/Create Minimalist File Browser in C#

Tags: c#, text-files, file-browser

I'm trying to make a program that stores files as `*.txt` based documents. I want to be able to click a button and pull up a list of currently stored files

`(Located in C:\ProgramData\ProgramName\Incidents)`

[image]

Above is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish where `140219-000727` is the name of the file, the rest isn't need. Clicking Open or Double Clicking would "Open" that file and parse the .txt into pre-existing forms on a WinForm application that I have already created.

What is the best way to go about doing this with a minimal hit on system resources?

Comment: you need a file browser or not? y did you need the txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what you are looking for. You can use the simplest mask "*.txt" to fetch all txt files and then using [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) cut the file name from the full path.
And later (on double click or button click) use the directory name + file name for opening:

```
//populating:
var files = Directory.GetFiles(YOUR_FOLDER_PATH, "*.txt");
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
    //assuming ListBox:
    listBox.Items.Add(filename);
}

//opening (from listbox)
var fileName = Path.Combine(YOUR_FOLDER_PATH, listBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a FolderBrowserDialog control.

```
var fileNames = new List<string>();
var fileContents = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.txt");
foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
{
    var fileName =new FileInfo(filePath).Name; 
    fileNames.Add(fileName);
    fileContents.Add(fileName, File.ReadAllText(filePath));
}
```